# Missing "Class", "Interface" and etc. options in the New menu

Tags: eclipse

Without any changes of setting in eclipse 2022-06 - I've lost this functionality.

I can't find solution about missing "Class", "Interface" and etc. options in the right-click New menu on subdirectory of "src". Please see the image.
What I've tried is:
`Played with all setting in "Customize prospective..." [Toolbar visibility, Shortcuts]`
`Started in cmd with -clean flag`
`Installed some older versions`

[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBkfS.png)

P.S.
This is happening on "Spring Boot Project", not in "Java Project"

Comment: You right-click on the wrong item. Right-click on the `com.example.demo` package (third element from top).

Comment: This is some work around. Thank you!

Comment: **Never ever delete the `.metadats` folder**. That's a hoax spread on Stack Overflow that can wreak your workspace and can cause data loss. When `-clean` does not work, use a fresh workspace. But in this case, Eclipse behaves just as it should and as documented.